Showing that $x/y$, where $x=x_1/x_0$ and $y=x_2/x_0$, is a local parameter of $x_0x_2^2=x_1(x_1-x_0)(x_1-2x_0)$ at $p=(0:0:1)$
This is question 5 from https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/II/AlgebraicGeometry/2023-2024/HW4.pdf.
Consider the curve
$$ x_0x_2^2 = x_1(x_1-x_0)(x_1-2x_0)$$
over a field of characteristic zero. I need to show $x/y$ is a local parameter at $p=(0:0:1)$ the point at infinity, where $x=x_1/x_0$ and $y=x_2/x_0$. Hence, find the divisor of $x$ and the divisor of $y$.
Firstly, I don't think this makes sense because $x/y$ isn't even defined at $p$. So I presume we mean $x_1/x_2$ is a local parameter. I can write
To show $x/y$ is a local parameter, I need to show directly that $x/y \in m_p$ but not $m_p^2$. The proof might go like 'Suppose $x/y$ is in $m_p^2$'. I don't know what to do next, we have to use the equation of the curve somehow. We know $m_p$ is non-empty since the curve is non-singular.
EDIT: I don't understand how $m_p = \langle x/y\rangle$ is even possible since $x_0\in m_p$ is not related to $x_1/x_2$ by a unit.
Could an argument go like this: $x/y=0$ iff $x_1=0$. Putting $x_1=0$ into the equation we have $x_0x_2^2=0$. So $(1:0:0)$ is a double root and $(0:0:1)$ is a single root. What are the details here?

are you sure P wasn't supposed to be $[0: 1: 0]$ ?

agree, my mistake! (one often studies the function $y/x$ on this curve and its behavior at $[0: 1: 0]$, hence my confusion)


$x_1$ is not a function, so it cannot be a local parameter. 2. Are you sure that $p=[0:0:1]$ is the point you want to consider? "Points at infinity" in $\Bbb P^2$ are usually those with the third coordinate zero.


@KReiser It is Q5 from here. Why is $(x_0,x_1,x_2)\to x_1$ not an element of $O_{X,p}$?

@ForgeBloyb $x_1$ is not well-defined in a neighborhood of $p$ because e.g. $[2: 2: 2] = [1: 1: 1]$.

@hunter Aha yes that was silly. I still have no idea what to do and I can't really find any examples of finding local parameters online.

Before we begin, it's important to clear up a misunderstanding: on a nonempty projective variety $X$ with coordinates $x_0,\cdots,x_n$, a non-constant homogeneous polynomial cannot be any sort of function on $X$ because it would have to take different values on different representatives of a point. Therefore you can't consider something like $x_i\in\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ unless $x_i=0$ on $X$, and in particular your statement "EDIT: I don't understand ... since $x_0\in m_p$" contains a false premise. In order to get a real honest function on a projective variety, one must dehomogenize, and the typical way one does this is by considering one of the standard affine opens $D(x_i)$, then sending a homogeneous polynomial $f \in k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ of degree $d$ to $f/x_i^d = f(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i})$.
To check whether $x/y = (x_1/x_0)/(x_2/x_0) = x_1/x_2$ is a local parameter on $V(x_0x_2^2-x_1(x_1-x_0)(x_1-2x_0))$ at $[0:0:1]$, let's dehomogenize near $[0:0:1]$.
Set $t=\frac{x_0}{x_2}$ and $u=\frac{x_1}{x_2}$, so our equation dehomogenizies to $t-u(u-t)(u-2t)$, our point dehomogenizes to $t=0$, $u=0$, and our function $x/y$ becomes $u$. So we're looking to check whether the image of $u$ generates the maximal ideal of $k[t,u]_{(t,u)}/(t-u(u-t)(u-2t))$ (let's assume we already know this is a DVR). One easy way to do this is to consider the quotient by the ideal generated by the image of $u$ - this is exactly $k[t,u]_{(t,u)}/(t-u(u-t)(u-2t),u) \cong k[t,u]_{(t,u)}/(t,u) \cong k$, a one-dimensional vector space - on the other hand, for a DVR $R$ over a field $k$ which also has residue field $k$, the dimension of the $k$-vector space $R/(r)$ is equal to the valuation of $r$, so $v(u)=1$ and it generates the maximal ideal, hence it is a local parameter.
To find the divisors of $x$ and $y$, you can repeat the above calculation a couple times at the points which are either zeroes or poles of $x$ and $y$. Or, if you want to try something similar to your last edit before I submitted the answer, you can calculate the divisors of $x_0$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ then subtract appropriately. Here's how that would look:

the divisor of $x_0$ is the intersection of $V(x_0)$ and $V(x_0x_2^2-x_1(x_1-x_0)(x_1-2x_0))$ taking in to account multiplicity, so we get $V(x_0,x_1^3)$, which is the point $[0:0:1]$ with multiplcity 3,
the divisor of $x_1$ is the intersection of $V(x_1)$ and $V(x_0x_2^2-x_1(x_1-x_0)(x_1-2x_0))$ taking in to account multiplicity, so we get $V(x_1,x_0x_2^2)$, which is the point $[0:0:1]$ with multiplcity 1 and the point $[1:0:0]$ with multiplicity 2,
the divisor of $x_2$ is the intersection of $V(x_2)$ and $V(x_0x_2^2-x_1(x_1-x_0)(x_1-2x_0))$ taking in to account multiplicity, so we get $V(x_2,x_1(x_1-x_0)(x_1-2x_0))$, which is the points $[1:0:0]$, $[1:1:0]$, and $[1:2:1]$, all with multiplicity one.

So the divisor of $x=\frac{x_1}{x_0}$ is $[0:0:1]+2\cdot[1:0:0]-3\cdot[0:0:1] = [0:0:1]-[1:0:0]$ and the divisor of $y=\frac{x_2}{x_0}$ is $[1:0:0]+[1:1:0]+[1:2:1] - 3\cdot[0:0:1]$.

Thanks for writing this. 1) Why do you write $x/y=x_1/x_2$? Is this just short hand? It only holds on $D(x_0)$ as far as I can tell (which doesn't contain $p$).  2) "lets assume we know this is a DVR" this is using the fact the curve is not singular at $p$? 3) How can you take the divisor of zeros and poles of $x_0$ if $x_0$ is not a function? I know that $(fg)=(f)+(g)$ if f,g are regular functions

I think I came up with another solution, would you mind checking my answer below?


I don't see how you got your second equality on "So the divisor of $x=\dots$"



All of this is happening as rational functions on $X$, i.e. inside the function field $K(X)$. The equality $x/y=x_1/x_2$ is certainly true as rational functions: on the open set  of $X$ where $x_0$ and $x_2$ are nonzero, the two functions are actually the same, and this is the definition of equality of rational functions on a variety. 2) Yes, correct. 3) $x_0$ is a (rational) section of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$, and you can compute divisors of rational sections of line bundles, and they play nicely with multiplication and division, which gives 4...


for rational sections $s,t$ of line bundles $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{M}$, the divisor associated to the rational section of $s/t$ of $\mathcal{L}\otimes\mathcal{M}^{-1}$ is the divisor of $s$ minus the divisor of $t$. In the future, may I suggest putting a little more information about what you're aware of or comfortable with in the question, so that answerers can take that in to account.

Thanks again. I have no idea what line bundles are and they aren't in the glossary of Hartshorne but I guess I can live with this division fact.

Line bundles are very much in Hartshorne, he just prefers the term invertible sheaf. One interpretation which is useful for this problem is that they're a way of recording things that are "almost" functions in the way that $x_0$ in this discussion is "almost" a function.

The line $x_1=0$ intersects the curve exactly three times by Bezout's theorem. Setting $x_1=0$, there are two solutions: $p$ and $q=(1:0:0)$. We will show $x_1=0$ has a double-intersection at $q$. On the chart $x_0\neq 0$, the line is given by $V(x_1/x_0)$ and the curve is
$$y^2 = x(x-1)(x-2)$$
and $q$ corresponds to $(0,0)$. Then, since $x-1$ and $x-2$ are units in $\mathcal{O}_{C,q}$,
$$2v_q(y)= v_q(x)$$
and so $v_q(x)\ge 2$. Therefore $v_q(x)=2$ (Bezout).
On the chart $x_2\neq 0$, the line $x_1=0$ is given by $V(x_1/x_2)=V(x/y)$ so $v_p(x/y)=3-v_q(x_1/x_0)=1$ (Bezout). So $x/y$ is a local parameter at $p$.
